# How to change the process id of a particular application in linux

Tags: linux, process, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I know this can be done in the user space and this has been answered [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122592/how-to-set-process-id-in-linux-for-an-specific-program).

However, I would like to be able to do it from with a kernel function/module.

***UPDATE***
**The c code (referred to from the other answered question) is part of the criu project. And the file `/proc/sys/kernel/ns_last_pid` does not exist in all systems. So, the code does not work on ubuntu. Is there any way I can make it work on ubuntu?**

**My final goal is**: fork a process and give it the ID of the parent.

**Steps**: staring with a process names P with id x.

1. Fork a process from within P. Name the child Q.
2. Assign the parent process P a temp id, say a.
3. Change the id of the child process Q and set it to be x.
4. Another kernel function will rewire the parenthood of child process Q. So that parent of P becomes parent of Q. In other words, the child process will take the identity of its parent.
5. Process P dies off since it is not waiting on any process.

I know how to do the steps 4-5. I have already implemented that. I am hacking another Linux kernel project. So, I have no other way around this. I have to implement this way.

Thanks all.

Comment: And what is your question? How to find the implementation of `/proc/sys/kernel/ns_last_pid`?

Comment: @CL. Why you down voted the question, now it is never gonna get answered.
I have updated the question with more details.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set process ID in Linux for an specific program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122592/how-to-set-process-id-in-linux-for-an-specific-program)

Comment: Since you expect process P to go away anyway, why not just `execve()` process Q? That will replace the process image of P with that of Q while retaining the same PID.

Answer (score 0):

The kernel assumes that a process is identified by its pid; changing the pid of an already-running process is unlikely to work without changing lots of code all over the kernel.

To give a process Q the same pid as a process P, use a third process R that sets `ns_last_pid` after P has terminated but before Q is started.
(For how to use `ns_last_pid`, see [this example](http://criu.org/Pid_restore).)