# Find Valgrind PID to invoke the application

Tags: c++, bash, valgrind, pid

I'm trying to run an application using valgrind tool. But the application needs the parent process id which invoke the application as an argument.

```
valgrind --leak-check=no --error-limit=no MyApplication {Parent_Process_ID}
```

But since valgrind process is still starting, i cannot get the pid from bash. I tried the following way as taking the previous process pid.

```
valgrind --leak-check=no --error-limit=no MyApplication $!
```

But it gives the process id of process ran before valgrind.

Can someone help me get the pid of valgrind here?

Comment: Parent Process ID is not required to run valgrind normally

Comment: You can re-write your application to get the parent process ID inside your program using `getppid()`. If you don't have control over your source code of your application, you can control the PID in Linux using ns_last_pid proc interface. Check http://efiop-notes.blogspot.de/2014/06/how-to-set-pid-using-nslastpid.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122592/how-to-set-process-id-in-linux-for-an-specific-program. With that proc file you can force the system to use the specific PID for next process creation (not sure how much guaranteed).

Comment: I dont have access to codes to rewrite the appication and it has the limitation of invoking through a parent process ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
( exec valgrind --leak-check=no --error-limit=no MyApplication $$ )
```

The parentheses create a subshell. `$$` expands to the PID of the shell itself.

Then `exec` loads the `valgrind` program into the current process, which keeps its PID the same, i.e. valgrind will have the same PID as the (sub-)shell.