# unable to write /proc/sys/kernel/ns_last_pid file

Tags: c++, linux-kernel, pid, file-writing, file-read

I want to edit the `ns_last_pid` file present in `/proc/sys/kernel`, but i'm getting the error of `Read-only file system`. How to resolve this?
This is what i've written to open the file.

```
int fd = open("/proc/sys/kernel/ns_last_pid", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0644);
            if (fd < 0) {
                cout<<strerror(errno)<<"\n";
                return 1;
            }
```

I've to write this file, change it's value. This file contains a single number represnting the last pid allocated to any process. I've to edit this so that i can get desired pid number for a process. like these guys are doing for their project **`CRIU`**(see first link).

[Pid_restore](https://criu.org/Pid_restore)(criu.org),

[How to set process ID in Linux for a specific program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122592/how-to-set-process-id-in-linux-for-a-specific-program)(stackoverflow answer)

**EDIT 1:** **Smallest reproducible example**

```
#include <fstream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#define _GNU_SOURCE             /* See feature_test_macros(7) */
#include <sched.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/file.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>

using namespace std;
    int main(){
            printf("Opening ns_last_pid...\n");   
            int fd = open("/proc/sys/kernel/ns_last_pid", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0644);
            if (fd < 0) {
                cout<<strerror(errno)<<"\n";
                return 1;
            }
            printf("Locking ns_last_pid...\n");
            if (flock(fd, LOCK_EX)) {
                close(fd);
                printf("Can't lock ns_last_pid\n");
                return 1;
            }
            printf("Done\n");
            char buf[100];
            int pid_max = 30000;
            snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%d", pid_max-1);

            printf("Writing pid-1 to ns_last_pid...\n");
            cout<<fd<<"\n";
            if (write(fd, buf, strlen(buf)) != strlen(buf)) {
               cout<<strerror(errno)<<"\n";
               printf("Can't write to buf\n");
               return 1;
            }
        
            printf("Done\n");
        
            printf("Cleaning up...");
            if (flock(fd, LOCK_UN)) {
                printf("Can't unlock");
                }
        
            close(fd);
        
            printf("Done\n");            
                      
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220997/discussion-on-question-by-user13145713-unable-to-write-proc-sys-kernel-ns-last).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For a program to change kernel files, it should be owned by root

   `sudo chown root program` // program is the executable(the binary)
2. set the setuid bit on the executable to execute a program with superuser access.
   with this it will run as root even if we execute it as any user on our machine.

   `sudo chmod u+s program`

Compile the source code and run the program with `sudo` to prevent other permission access errors.

Thanks to **TedLyngmo** for suggesting this solution.

Comment: `chmod u+s` is a really bad idea in general, I would avoid advising it. Running the program with `sudo` is enough, you don't need to give any user the privilege of running it as `root`.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I unerstand what you're saying, but this is a part of project where i need to do many tests like these.