# joined process cannot write ns_last_pid of the container

Tags: process, kernel, linux-containers, linux-namespaces, runc

A process from a host joined a container's namepsace and is trying to write `ns_last_pid` file present in `/proc/sys/kernel/ns_last_pid`. but it is giving an error of `Read only file system`.

whereas i'm able to do this on the host's `ns_last_pid` file via this solution
[unable to write /proc/sys/kernel/ns_last_pid file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63738738/unable-to-write-proc-sys-kernel-ns-last-pid-file)

How to solve this issue?

Comment: What kind of container are you using ?  If it is LXC, the configuration file of the container specifies the access rights on /sys. For example, if you have "lxc.mount.auto = proc:mixed", this means "mount /proc as read-write, but remount /proc/sys and /proc/sysrq-trigger read-only for security / container isolation purposes."

Comment: @RachidK. I'm using a `runc` container https://github.com/opencontainers/runc

Answer (score 0):

You have to run your container in `--privileged` mode to be able to write to `/proc/sys/kernel/ns_last_pid`.